# Is the set $\left\{ u\in L^{2}\left(\Omega\right):0\leq u\left(x\right)\leq1\,a.e.\right\} $ closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

If $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is bounded, closed and convex with smooth boundary,
is the set $\left\{ u\in L^{2}\left(\Omega\right):0\leq u\left(x\right)\leq1\,a.e.\right\} $ closed in $L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)$?

Comment: What is your work on this problem so far?

Comment: Have you tried using a sequence argument? Note that any sequence of functions in your set is uniformly bounded almost everywhere by 1.

Comment: If $(f_n)$ converges in the $p$-th power of the mean, then there is a subsequence that converges a.e.; the result is trivial considering this.